# cache_dir must be a directory

Tags: error, exception

Please excuse my English. I'm an IT student and now I'm practising with magento.

When i try to change the design `System/General/Design`, i get an error.

> Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons. Error
>   log record number: 1068330729847

I also get a error when a reach the `CMS/Page` option

> Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.
>   Error log record number: 227607087873

i already tried to change the `null` to `tmp` in the `File.php` file and I also created a new folder in the root map.

Can you help me out please

Comment: Hi, Welcome to stackMagento. In order to get more help from this community, please add the log errors that you have got. You can find them at `var/report/<log_record_number>`

Comment: Thank you, this is just a part of it.                    Ha:5:{i:0;s:29:"cache_dir must be a directory";i:1;s:4326:"#0 /public/sites/www.beautyenhaargeheimen.com/lib/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php(154): Zend_Cache::throwException('cache_dir must ...')
#1 /public/sites/www.beautyenhaargeheimen.com/lib/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php(121): Zend_Cache_Backend_File->setCacheDir('temp/')
#2 /public/sites/www.beautyenhaargeheimen.com/lib/Zend/Cache.php(153): Zend_Cache_Backend_File->__construct(Array)

Answer (score 3):

Ivan Djakie,Issue was `tmp folder is not created`.Magento use `Zend Framework and it Cache system`. For zend frmaework there need `a tmp folder in magento dir` in where magento is save  `Zend Cache`. So you need to create a `folder whose name is  tmp`

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that the title of this question is the error that is being reported within the report log file `var/report/1068330729847` if this is not the case please post the output from one of the log files here.

Based on my assumption it sounds like your installation of Magento does not have a folder for cache. [Magento wiki](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/install-privs-after) provides information on configuring the permissions but ensure you have a folder within your project root for `var` and within there are folder for `cache` these should be read and writable by your webserver but again the documentation will provide the recommended folder permissions.

Comment: thank you for your quick respons. now i get the 403 error message